# Why does the data in My Angular Service keep getting wiped?

Tags: angular

I have a component that uploads a file and saves the data in a service

`this.csvDataService.saveCSV(csv)`

Then I redirect to another service:

`this.router.navigate(['/map'])`

in my map component:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getSnappedRoute()
  }

  getSnappedRoute() {
    let inputCSV = this.csvDataService.getCSV()
    this.googleMapsService.tracePathOnRoad(inputCSV).subscribe(routeLocations => {
      this.snappedRoute = routeLocations['json']['snappedPoints'];
      this.openMap();
    })
  };

  openMap() {
    let mapProp = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(this.snappedRoute[0]['location']['latitude'], this.snappedRoute[0]['location']['longitude']),
      zoom: 5,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.hybrid
    }

    let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp)
  }
```

This works well for the first time, however if I refresh the page, the csv data in my `csvDataService` is gone.

Comment: Any time you refresh the page using the "Reload the page" button, your Angular application is reloaded. This will cause the entire application to be destroyed and recreated. If you need your application to retain data across reloads, consider storing the information in local storage or some other system such as firebase.

Comment: Where do you provide the service? What do you mean with "refresh the page"? Angular doesn't keep state between page reloads. Hint: If you a Google Maps library that is not specific to Angular 2+, it's susceptible to not invoke change detection when it calls callbacks because the code runs outside Angulars zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data in an Angular service is stored in memory. Refreshing the page, like restarting an application, clears that memory. There is no reason to expect application state to persist over a reload. This is true whether you are putting it in a service, a component, or any other object.

If you need it to persist, use a cookie or local storage, or send the data to a database.